# Cannot retrieve file list from Azure File Storage using REST API and curl

Tags: rest, azure, curl, azure-storage

I'm trying to retrieve the list of files stored in an Azure File Storage account using the REST API and curl, I correctly computed headers according to the documentation by using the shared key , but curl request neither returns the files list nor any error message.

Here is my request and the response:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: SharedKey myaccount:bAJKeY0xyOZLSJOLDoHfXXOqfA4kOGo1DVFP3BejhY8=" -H "x-ms-date:Mon, 13 Aug 2018 15:22:31 GMT" -H "x-ms-version:2017-07-29" --url https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydir?restype=directory&comp=list

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 52.239.140.8...

* Connected to myaccount.file.core.windows.net (52.239.140.8) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: *.file.core.windows.net (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: CN=*.file.core.windows.net
*    start date: Thu, 09 Nov 2017 05:42:03 GMT
*    expire date: Sat, 09 Nov 2019 05:42:03 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,ST=Washington,L=Redmond,O=Microsoft Corporation,OU=Microsoft IT,CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 5
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol

GET /myshare/mydir?restype=directory HTTP/1.1

Host: myaccount.file.core.windows.net

User-Agent: curl/7.47.0

Accept: */*

Authorization: SharedKey 
myaccount:bAJKeY0xyOZLSJOLDoHfXXOqfA4kOGo1DVFP3BejhY8=
x-ms-date:Mon, 13 Aug 2018 15:22:31 GMT
x-ms-version:2017-07-29

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Last-Modified: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 16:11:14 GMT

ETag: "0x8D5AC597FF96B3D"

Server: Windows-Azure-File/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

x-ms-request-id: 75d6d7c8-f01a-0011-5b19-33104d000000

x-ms-version: 2017-07-29

x-ms-server-encrypted: true

Date: Mon, 13 Aug 2018 15:22:29 GMT

{ [5 bytes data]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host myaccount.file.core.windows.net left intact
```

No XML with file list is returned.
I tried to retrieve the share list under myaccount and it works, as well as downloading a single file, but I cannot receive the list of files under a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

1. See url in curl command

   ```
   --url https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydir?restype=directory&comp=list
   ```

   You forget to put the url in `""` so the parameter `&comp=list` is cut because `&` is a reserved sign. This is also proved by the output `GET /myshare/mydir?restype=directory HTTP/1.1`.
2. Commonly speaking, if the url misses the `comp` parameter, we should get error message AuthenticationFailed because `comp` is used in generating SharedKey. However you get `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` with the SharedKey.

   Based on the response headers you get, I guess you also missed the `comp` when constructing the SharedKey, so the SharedKey and url is capable to get [directory properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-directory-properties) correctly.